Current state of vampires in the Marvel Comic Universe
Potential spoiler alert, since this question is sparked by the 2024 Marvel Comics summer crossover epic "Blood Hunt" (which is about half done at this time).
Vampires are rampaging across the Marvel Earth. There is a strategy behind the rampage, with the major heroes being targeted first. Of those heroes, Dr. Strange is particularly on the bullseye. The sneak attack was successful. Dr. Strange was bitten by a vamp, and became one.
Immediately.
For comic fans of a certain age, we recall Dracula and Strange fighting back in the 1980's. Dracula bit the Sorcerer Supreme, but the transformation between dead and undead took three days and nights. (Which resonates with classic vampire lore).
This speedy conversion rate is taking place all thru the linked stories, with heroes and normal humans alike.
The question I'm circling to is if there is an in-universe answer for this "zombie-esque" bite and superspeed conversion? I'm not a scholar of vampire-supernatural action in the comics, so I could easily have missed this upgrade. Or is it just something we're to ignore for the expediency of plot dynamics?

I strongly suspect that the writers haven't read any previous Marvel comics featuring vampires. They just checked that they existed in canon and then made up their own lore as they went along

Having not read the event, is it over yet? Perhaps this speedy conversion will be explained in the narrative, maybe even made clear that it holds the secret to its reversal?
I'm old enough to remember when they (temporarily, obvs) eliminated vampires from the MU using the Darkhold.

More Spoiler Warnings: The primary reason Dr. Strange has been targeted is due to his previous casting of the Montessi Formula, and to prevent him casting it again. That, and other small moments/comments by characters, suggests the writer(s) have done their due diligence in research. They're not bluntly ignoring the canon.
